# Retrieve executed command in child_process

Tags: node.js

If I have a process that I executed using `child_process` like,

```
child_process.spawn('psql', ['-U user', '-h localhost', '-p 5432']);
```

or in any `child_process` execution mechanism like `exec()` and `fork()`.

How do I **retrieve** the executed command string `psql -U user -h localhost -p 5432`?

Answer (score 0):

In your example the command will be executed like:

`psql '-U user' '-h localhost' '-p 5432'`

that's because the way you're feeding the args array.

Try that:

```
child_process.spawn('psql', ['-U', 'user', '-h', 'localhost', '-p', '5432']);
```

Comment: Ok, let us assume that I did it that way, is there any way to retrieve the executed command string?